# Android studio (Api google maps ) Api

Tags: android, google-maps

Hola estoy realizando un trabajo en en el cual debo ocupar una api de **google maps** , ya obtuve mi api y la agregué  a mi código pero siempre que la quiero correr en mi celular o maquina  aparece este error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

Estuve investigando y le agregué lo de multiDexEnable pero la abre en pantalla en color negro y se cierra ,cabe destacar que utilize la plantilla de **google maps** que viene en **android studio**,le agrego  mi api donde debo ponerla  de ,la corro y me marca ese error .

Espero puedan ayudarme .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que veo tienes un problema con Multidex. 
Android soporta cierta cantidad de memoria para las librerías, así es su arquitectura.
Cuando se usan as librerías de google maps y en general cuando se usan las de play-services es necesario habilitar la opción multidex.

Revisa, mi  solución para este caso: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39814686/3377472

Aquí sale la información oficial  .https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Si tienes dudas, sigue el hilo de esta respuesta

PD: Trata de escribir mejor :)